# Can I interpolate a SASS variable into a SASS selector property value?

Tags: sass, string-interpolation

I want to interpolate a variable value into a SASS prpoerty value. I dont want to interpolate the property name as [defined here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/declarations#interpolation)

I want to achieve this in css using a sass variable but i dont want to specify the variables units in its definition.

```
.selector {
 width: 90%;
}
```

in sass I want to do something like this:

```
$variable: 90

.selector {
width: $variable% // note the % on the end!
```

but I cant find clear documentation on how to do it.

Using basic interpolation I can do this:

```
$variable: 90%
.selector {
  width: #{$width};
}
```

So the string interpolation works for property values, but both of the following result in errors:

```
$variable: 90
.selector {
  width: #{$width}%;
}
```

```
$variable: 90
.selector {
  width: #{$width%};
}
```

to clarify, I dont want to do this:

```
$variable: 90%

.selector {
 width: $variable
}
```

because I may want to use the variable as px, em, %, vw etc.

So, how do add % (or any other string) to the end of my variable?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
$variable: 90
.selector {
  width: #{$width}+'%';
}
```

Comment: your code makes no sense, and is also invalid.